# Paging through unanswered questions removes the unanswered filter

Tags: bug, mobile

If you use the "unanswered"  menu item, you get a page of the first top 20 or so unaswered questions, ordered by votes.  But if you try to advance through the list using the page navigation buttons, the "unanswered" filter appears to go away, and page 2 etc. is just for all questions, including answered ones.

This appears to happen only on the mobile-responsive site; using the "full site", paging through "unanswered" appears to work correctly.

Comment: I'd usually say whilst it's fine to post on a per site meta you'd get more traction/attention by posting it to main meta but looks like someone [already posted it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334658/345161).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Apparently SO is special -- the comments at that MSE post are talking about some UX elements we don't have.

Comment: I _think_ the comments are on about the "Custom Filters"... don't know how accessible that is on the mobile site though.